# Review ESP12 standalone module schematics

Tags: schematics, esp8266, 3.3v

I am currently building a private design project. For this I need an ESP12E. I try to get it running with only 3.3V (VIN on schematics). In addition, I would like to be able to program the chip later via TX/RX with a USB adapter. Since I had so far some failed attempts with boards, I would like to ask now first of all whether this time everything is correct or I have built in errors:
[image]

On J1 there will be some devices and transistors later, but I want to build it slowly up to fix errors for debugging reasons :)

I thank you already once warmly for answers!

P.S.: If someone wants to have a look on the PCB too:
[image]

---

EDIT, here is the new PCB:
[image]
(Just updated PCB after comments; 3.3V line 1.5mm; data lines 1.0mm; GND area on the bottom with VIAs; looking better?)

Comment: Those are some narrow traces!

Comment: The edit misses sone traces, are they on the bottom? Can you show them? Ground preferably is solid without too many/long interruptions. I would have cut the pcb just above R1/J2. Do you need screwholes? Put a ground via next to every signal via, as close as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There needs to be wider traces for power and ground. Traces are resistors and the thicker they are the less resistance and inductance they have. More resistance and inductance means a voltage drop when the load (microprocessor) uses more current.

The ground needs to be a lot thicker (as thick as you can get it), it might be better to put a ground on the bottom layer and use vias to go to the top layer.

Grounds need to be very low resistance and inductance and not daisy chain loads (use a fill or use the entire bottom layer).

Comment: Ah okay I'll do that. But the schematics looks right? Why easyEDA uses this small traces aa standard setting? Just curious

Comment: It's the responsibility of the designer to determine trace size. Schematics look ok

Comment: Just updated the PCB; should look/work better now? :)

Comment: If the blue shading is a ground plane, better remove it from the module antenna area. More VCC decoupling is good, preferably add 100 uF or so.

Comment: Thanks for the advise @Wirewrap

Comment: You could make C1 22uF, with MLCC caps adding lower values like 0.1uF is legacy thinking.